# Хочу выровнять название программы по центру(заголовок)

Tags: android, android-studio

Создал проект, используя шаблон Navigation Drawer Activity.

Хочу выровнять название программы по центру, но у меня не получается.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно на принт-скрине название программы с левой стороны эмулятора смартфона, нужно выровнять название по центру.

С простыми надписями всё несколько проще их спокойно редактируешь в xml. Но в случае названия программы, само название программы находиться в значениях xml-ки стринг и является ресурсом 0_о !!! (вот так поворот). Пытался  в файле MainActivity с ним поработать но у меня не вышло.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создайте файл `partial_toolbar` в `res/layout`.

Код **partial_toolbar:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
    app:title="">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_toolbar_title"
        style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/title"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Если вы создавали ваше activity, через `blanc Android Studio`, то у вас должен быть файл `app_bar_main` и там должен быть тэг `AppBarLayout`. Нужно заinclude(ить) ваш partial_toolbar.

Пример кода **app_bar_main:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.activity.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/partial_toolbar"
            layout="@layout/partial_toolbar" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Также, если хотите, можете поменять программно текст, найдите виджет `text_toolbar_title` и вызвать у него метод `toolbarTitle.setText("Your text");`, есть небольшое НО: нужно будет в AndroidManifeste свойству label поставить пусто.

Пример:

```
    <!--Main-->
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.activity.MainActivity"
        android:label=""
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
```

Надеюсь вам помог мой ответ. Это решение работает для меня.

Comment: Спасибо :3 большое

Comment: Единственный минус в шаблоне Navigation Drawer Activity отрубает кнопу (менюшки)

Comment: Что имеется ввиду под "отрубает"?

Comment: значок Hamburger menu (три полосочки) его нету. и самой кнопки на лейауте нету

Comment: надо разметку посмотреть, файла content_main и активити, фрагмента, где лежит сам DrawerLayout

Comment: заменил в content_main, элемент ConstraintLayout свойство tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main на tools:showIn="@layout/partial_toolbar" и в активити маин, элемент  NavigationView  свойство app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main" на app:headerLayout="@layout/partial_toolbar". И все равно не заработало.

Comment: Не, showIn правильно стоял. Нужен код на DrawerLayout, там есть include на app_bar_main?

Comment: Да есть DrawerLayout да  <include layout="@layout/app_bar_main" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />. Да там есть include на app_bar_main

Comment: в __ заменил  layout="@layout/app_bar_main" на layout="@layout/partial_toolbar"  программа не запустилась )))

Answer (score 2):

Постараюсь ответить по пунткам:

1. Этот титульник практически всегда не должен соответствовать названию программы. Просто в вашем случае он совпадает, из-за того, что так выставляется по умолчанию. Обычно титульник в тулбаре отображает название activity/fragmenta-а, или его содержимого.
2. Делать его по центру - не совсем соотвествие гайдланам Material design-a. Если же хотите, то гуглите [примерно так](https://www.google.ru/search?q=android%20create%20custom%20toolbar&rlz=1C1CHBF_enRU745RU745&oq=android%20create%20custom%20toolbar&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.7351j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)
3. Все строки заносятся в strings.xml. Так сделано специально, для удобной поддержки локализации.